# Installing door on crawlspace access

Tags: doors, crawlspace

I'd like to install a door on the crawlspace entrance in our basement.
One problem I'm running into is the radon remediation pipe is bracketed to one of the walls.
Any ideas on how to frame this out?
[image]
I assume I could create the frame to the left of the pipe, but I'm not sure how to fill in the gap above and below the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Your photo doesn't show much of the area to the left of the opening, but from what is visible, this opening seems a perfect fit for a sliding door. The framing would be above and below the opening, perhaps a stop plate to the right of the PVC, but the door would have a slot to engage the pipe. If extreme sealing is required, weather stripping applied to the stop plate and around the door cut out should give a good closure.

The bottom support framing could contain a long door slide to provide reduced friction, or simply wax the slot in which the door slides and the mating edge of the door. Moisture may come into play if the wood swells after time and should be considered when constructing the assembly.

Comment: The sliding door idea is a good one. A hinged door would seem to be really inconvenient for any position except for being folded all the way back against the left side wall. In the end that makes it the same as the slider in the open position.

Comment: I looked a little closer when I got home. The piece of the pipe that bends then goes down to the floor is catty corner to the wall its mounted on. It doesn't look like the door would be able to slide between the pipe and the wall. Here are a couple other pictures. Picture 1: http://imgur.com/FToY1cy      Picture 2: http://imgur.com/Bhwn32h

Comment: Yes, that would make things a little trickier. You'd want to fill in the gap between the vertical pipe more or less permanently, but then displace the contact line of the sliding portion to match the pipe. The door would have a peculiar cut-out shape but should still butt up against the pipe, sealing the opening.

Comment: Thanks, Fred! Looks like it's time to break out the jigsaw..